# Centos 6 - Plesk 11 - MaxRequestLen - cannot modify mod_fcgid

Tags: centos, plesk, mod-fcgid

I have just installed Plesk 11 on Centos 6 and I cannot upload files larger than 17-18 Mo.

> [warn] [client ] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16777368 (so far)
>   exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216)

I set my php.ini like this:

```
post_max_size = 150M

file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 128M

memory_limit = 256M
```

- I tried to modify in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf`
  by adding

  `FcgidMaxRequestLen 30000000`

and restarted apache; I still got the same error.

Here's what I tried:

- I found that FcgidMaxRequestLen was also set in this file
  /usr/local/psa/admin/conf/templates/default/domain/domainVirtualHost.php
  changed, saved, apache restarted.. same error
- I tried to set FcgidMaxRequestLen with different sizes, 1 giga, 20 mo ect still same error.
- I tried to change http.conf and add this:

  < IfModule mod_fcgid.c >
    MaxRequestLen 20000000
  < /IfModule >

I am restarting apache for each and every change. There must be some config file that I am missing but I don't know where

Comment: Please move the solution into an answer below and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok here is the solution:

http://stuffthatspins.com/2013/01/22/exceeds-maxrequestlen-16777216-plesk-mod_fcgid-unable-to-upload-large-files/

to reconfigure domain with centos:

/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain yourdomain.com

/sbin/service apache restart

/sbin/service psa restart